# How to disable FMX ComboBox Mouse Wheel scroll

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

How can I disable the mouse wheel scroll on a FMX TComboBox when hovering over it?
I've tried overriding the `MouseWheel` method without any luck. I'm most likely doing it wrong as I'm not experienced with overriding. REF: [MouseWheel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.MouseWheel)

I've gone ahead and removed `Inherited`:

```pascal
type
  TComboBoxOverride = class(TComboBox)
    procedure MouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean); override;
  end;

// I've tried changing the control on the class overriding the method. No luck
cbbServerMap: TComboBoxOverride;

{ TComboBoxOverride }

procedure TComboBoxOverride.MouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
end;
```

I've found the following SO post for VCL and DevEx but I'm struggling to convert it to FMX, Ref: [How to suppress mouse wheel in TcxComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399121/how-to-suppress-mouse-wheel-in-tcxcombobox)

When setting a breakpoint on the `TCustomComboBox.MouseWheel` method I can see that it ignores my override.

Comment: Set Handled to True.

Comment: Unfortunately this does nothing.

Comment: The only way your override would be ignored is if your combo box control is not actually of type `TComboBoxOverride`. Are you sure that class in the fmx file is correct? Code you presented here should work, there is something else going on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its correct. I manually set it and then when I hit save the IDE asks me if I want to convert it back to TComboBox and I say no leaving it at the override.

Can anyone preproduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `OnMouseWheel` event, simply put `Abort;`.

For example:

```
procedure TfrmMinorInjury.cboDischargetypeMouseWheel(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Abort;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same task but for memos in scrollbox.
My solution is

1. handle mouse wheel in scrollbox.OnMouseWheel. Set Handle := true there.
2. call directly scrollbox.OnMouseWheel  in memo's OnMouseWheel

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant by calling the onMouseWheel event directly?
I've tried `cbb1.OnMouseWheel(cbb1, [], 0, Handled);` right after Setting Handled to true however it seems to crash the application as it loops

Comment: you have to call parent's handler not self
```
procedure TForm1.Memo1OnMouseWheel(.....);
begin
   scrollBox1.OnmouseWheel(.....);
end;
```